# Calling a variable from one class in another

Tags: java, eclipse, class, contentpane

I am writing the code for a primitive address book for one of my classes, and it is required that we use a class for the address book itself, and then another class for putting in new entries. I understand this, but when I call the class method for entering new contacts, I want to change the GUI. I am using JFrame, and so for my GUI base i am using the `contentPane`. In my first class I created my `contentPane` with a basic GUI:

```
public class Address extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    Container contentPane;

    public Address()
    {
        super();
        contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Address Book");
        setSize(775,775);
        setLocation(0,0);
        setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
}
```

And now in my second class, the input one, I want to clear the `contentPane` with `contentPane.removeAll()`.

```
class Entries
{
    public void newContact()
    {
        contentPane.removeAll();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing in my class Entries is recognizing `contentPane` and other variables i am attempting to modify. Is there a special way to name the `contentPane` and other variables in class Address so that they are usable in Entries, or do i need to recreate the variable?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an object of `Entries` you need to give it a reference to the `Address` object so you can use its variables. I'm not sure how your program layout is set up, but if `Entries` is created within `Address` you'd call `Entries entry = new Entry(this);` or if it is from a parent to both classes you'd need to set up variables...

```
Address address = new Address();
Entries entry = new Entry(address);
```

Code for how you'd access it in Entries:

```
class Entries
{
    private Address reference;

    public Entries(Address reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public void newContact()
    {
        reference.contentPane.removeAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this didn't short cut the question or work its way around. It worked immediately and is usable in any situation relating to my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, when i tried this on a larger scale using arrays and JLabels, it broke down. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the reference of contentPane to Entries either as a constructor arg or add a contentPane property(getter,setter) to Entries.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to access stuff, either you duplicate the variable and give the contentPane in the Entries constructor :

```
private Container contentPane;

public Entries(Container contentPane) {
    this.contentPane = contentPane;
}
```

Or you create a getter on your contentPane in the Address class and pass the contentPane.

Both solutions are quite bad in my opinion however, maybe you should consider extending a JPanel for your entries class, and add the Entries to your main contentPane, then you will be able to do whatever UI stuff you want in the Entries class.

Comment: I am not familiar with how to pass things. even if it is not necessarily the best way, it may be good knowledge. Could you explain here/provide me with a link that would explain how to pass the contentPane?